# Angular UI bootstrap datepicker correct range dateFrom, dateTo

Tags: angular, datepicker

Hi I have two  Angular UI Bootstrap Datepickers whichs sets dates in text inputs to dateFrom and dateTo values.

I'd like to prevent user against an action when he choose incorrect date range.

For example. When user sets dateFrom to 2017-06-12, he should't be able to set dateTo smaller than 2017-06-12 on dateTo datePicker.

Bad range is for example from 2017-06-12 to 2017-06-09.
How could I prevent user aganinst that actions? I'm trying to set range in one datepicker popup after selection date in second datepicker popup, but I don't know ho solve it.

Below I show my html and angular js code:

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 form-group">

            <label for="usr"  class="control-label">Date From:</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="dt" is-open="datepickers.dt" datepicker-options="dateOptionsDt" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" readonly />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event, 'dt')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                </span>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">

            <label for="usr" class="control-label">Date To:</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="dtSecond" is-open="datepickers.dtSecond" datepicker-options="dateOptionsDtSecond" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" readonly />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event, 'dtSecond')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                </span>


            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="searchByDates()" style="margin-top: 24px;">Search</button>
            </span>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Angular js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap','ngSanitize','ngAnimate']);
app.controller('postsController', function($scope) {


    $scope.initDate = function(){


      $scope.dateFrom = null;

      $scope.dateTo = null;

    }
    $scope.today = function(){


       $scope.dateFrom = new Date();

      $scope.dateTo = new Data();
    };

    $scope.datepickers = {
        dt: false,   // date From
        dtSecond: false // date To
      }
    $scope.today = function(){

        $scope.dateFrom = new Date();
        $scope.dateTo = new Date();
    };

  $scope.initDate();
  //$scope.today();


  $scope.dateOptionsDt = {

    formatYear: 'yyyy',
    maxDate: new Date(2017,05,22), 
    minDate: new Date(2017,05,22),
    startingDay: 1
  };
   $scope.dateOptionsDtSecond = {

    formatYear: 'yyyy',
    maxDate: new Date(2017,05,16), 
    minDate: new Date(2017,05,13),
    startingDay: 1
  };


  $scope.open = function($event,which) {

      $event.preventDefault();
      $event.stopPropagation();
      $scope.correctRange(which);
      $scope.datepickers[which] = true;

  }

  $scope.popup1 = {
    opened: false
  };

  $scope.popup2 = {
    opened: false
  };

  $scope.correctRange = function(which){

      var dateFrom = $scope.dateFrom;
      var dateTo = $scope.dateTo;

      if(which == 'dt'){

          if(dateTo != null){

              $scope.dateOptionsDtSecond.maxDate = new Date(2017,05,30);


          }
          //$scope.dateOptions.maxDate = new Date();

      }
      else if(which=='dtSecond'){


      }

  }

});
```

Here is example of working code:
plnkr.co/edit/HE4qatujlWVxf9kzPqM6?p=preview

Comment: Did you go through the UI date picker docs ? There's an option to pass min-date. Set min-date to the output of first date picker.

Comment: You suggest to read Date from ng-model: for example:  minDate: $scope.dt; ?

Comment: yes, that should solve the issue.

Comment: I'm trying do something like that but it dosen't work ;( Could you give me any exampley? I'll be very greatful.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle ? Also try to change the value of dateOptionsDtSecond minDate to $scope.dateOptionsDt.maxDate;
`$scope.dateOptionsDtSecond = {

    formatYear: 'yyyy',
    maxDate: new Date(2017,05,16), 
    minDate: new Date(2017,05,13),
    startingDay: 1
  };`

Comment: Now I'm going to work. I'll write here about some minutes after 7 am ;).

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/HE4qatujlWVxf9kzPqM6?p=preview - I've created here example. But I think for example: maxDate in $scope.dateOptionsDt should have actual setted value of $scope.dateOptionsDtSecond. How could I do that?